# Overlapping box

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am having problems overlaping two boxes. Should I use absolute positioning? z-index or what techniques are out there? By the way I want them to overlap is just that I want to make sure it works cross modern browsers. IE8 or +

I cant push the black box to the center why?
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<title>Metropolitan State Hospital Intranet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Home.css">
</head>

<body>

        <div id="masthead">

            <div id="logo">
                Logo here
            </div><!--end logo-->

            <div id="header">
                <div id="horizontalMainMenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us     |</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us   |</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Metro Link   |</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">WaRMSS Login  </a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <br style="clear:left;"><!--I used float:left in the css to stack the list items now I need to clear it-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--end header-->

        </div><!--end masthead-->

        <div id="container">
            <div id="left_col">
                <div id="verticalMainMenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Air Quality Control</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CalATERS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Email Encryption</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Employee Guide</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Patient Special Function Requests</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Request Home Address <br> Confidentiality Form</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Travel Store</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div><!--verticalMainMenu ends here-->
            </div><!--left_col ends here-->

            <div id="page_content">
                <div id="horizontalBodyMenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Clinical</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Administrative</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <br style="clear:left">
                </div>


            </div><!--page_content ends here-->
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            Footer
        </div><!--end footer-->

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* CSS layout */
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#masthead {
    min-width: 600px;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:yellow;/*I dont know what color this is in the template*/

}

#header {
        background-color:yellow;/*I dont know what color this is in the template*/
        height:300px;
}

#container {
    clear: both;
    min-width: 600px;

}

#left_col {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:red; /*I dont know what color this is in the template*/

}

#page_content {
    background-color:black; 
    margin:-50px 0 0 0;
    width:95%;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
}
/* CSS common layout ends here*/

/* horizontalMainMenu starts here*/
#horizontalMainMenu{
    width:100%;
    background-color:transparent;
}
#horizontalMainMenu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
}
#horizontalMainMenu ul li{
    display:inline;
}
#horizontalMainMenu ul li a{
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    padding:5px 9px;
}

/*horizontalMainMenu ends here*/

/*Body Menu Starts here*/

#horizontalBodyMenu ul{
    list-style:none;
}

#horizontalBodyMenu ul li{
    display:inline;
    }


/* horizontalBodyMenu ends here*/

#horizontalMainMenu ul li a:visited{
    color:white;
}
#horizontalMainMenu ul li a:hover,#mainMenu ul li .current{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#0b75b2;
}

#verticalMainMenu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;/*removes the default bulltets*/
}
#verticalMainMenu li{
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
    background-image:url('');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:.5em;
    line-height:200%;
}
#verticalMainMenu li a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#0b75b2;

}
```

Comment: The diagonally striped bar doesn't look good, IMHO.

Comment: the second picture is my developer test site. The first one is the current site but using absolute positioning... which is not a very good across browsers and screen resolutions.

Comment: Regarding the update you made to your question (which is quite far from the scope of the original question..), is your page supposed to be fixed width (and centered)? Or is it supposed to stretch to the full width of the screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do it normally, and then pull "Box 2" upwards with `margin-top: -80px`.

This will work in "all browsers".

Here's a good article concerning negative margins:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Answer (score 0):

You need to position box2 relative to box1.  Lookup html relative positioning.

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Yeah I just dint think about this.